# Angular-formly clean error

Tags: validation, angular-formly

I have two fields whose validation logic depends on each other. Sometimes field 1 raises a validation error, but modifying the value of field 2 should make the value in field 1 as a valid one. Any idea if there's a way to do that in Angular-formly?

For example, let's say I have a field called dateOne and another one is called dateTwo. dateTwo should come after dateOne. If I enter dateOne as 2016-08-29 and set dateTwo to 2016-08-28, my validator for dateTwo returns an error, saying dateTwo should come after dateOne. If I set dateTwo to 2016-08-30, the error will go away and my from becomes valid, which works fine. However, if user changes dateOne to 2016-08-20, my form is technically valid, but it still remains invalid as I need a way to remove the validation error from dateTwo and make the form valid.

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you want to achieve?

Comment: I added an example to the description.

Comment: I figured it out by setting validateOnModelChange: true in extras.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which calendar you are using, if you are using bootstrap then it is very simple.

in dateOne textbox:

```
 max-date="model.dateTow"
```

and in date two:

```
min-date= "model.dateOne"
```

Once you select the start date, end date calendar will disable all the dates before selected date,

Once you select the end date, start date calendar will disable all the dates after end date.

[See the complete article](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1198/angularjs-bootstrap-datepicker-enable-disable-dates-with-configuration-example)

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out by setting validateOnModelChange: true in extras.